# (java) My prime number generator works only up to 200

Tags: java, primes

I'm using Eratosthenes' sieve as my framework. It works from 2-199 but it just stops printing values beyond that.
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Scratchpad
{
    public Scratchpad()
    {

    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> makeList(int max)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
        {
            arrList.add(i);
        }
        return arrList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> removeMult(ArrayList<Integer> arrList, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((arrList.get(i) % n == 0) && arrList.get(i) != n)
            {
                arrList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return arrList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> primesOnly(ArrayList<Integer> arrList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++)
        {
            removeMult(arrList, arrList.get(i));
            System.out.println(arrList.get(i));
        }
        return arrList;
    }
}
```

It works for all primes 2-199.

[cmd screen cap (sorry for shitty crop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLuB5.png)

Comment: Show the main you're using

Comment: Cannot reproduce - `Scratchpad sp = new Scratchpad(); ArrayList<Integer> numbers = sp.makeList(500); sp.primesOnly(numbers); System.out.println(numbers);` prints the prime numbers up to 500

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine with the following main:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scratchpad s = new Scratchpad();

    ArrayList nums = s.makeList(500);

    System.out.println(nums);
    System.out.println(s.primesOnly(nums));

}
```

I think you probably just only generated a list of numbers up to 200.

Comment: I tried it again this morning and it worked. idk what went wrong.